Deno 2 configuration file not detected when using compile command
Using Deno 2, I've been getting the error message " Relative import path "@jdeighan/vllu/llutils.js" not prefixed with / or ./ or ../" on and off for a while now, even though my deno.jsonc file contains "@jdeighan/vllu/": "./src/lib/" in the imports section. FYI, through everything I do, the "current directory" is ALWAYS set to my project root, where the deno.jsonc file resides, and the file ./src/lib/llutils.js file exists.
I've finally determined that the problem occurs when I'm running a script installed via "deno install -fgA". Looking in my ~/.deno/bin folder, after installing a script named compile.js, I see 2 files named 'compile' and 'compile.cmd' containing:
#!/bin/sh
# generated by deno install
deno "run" "--allow-all" "--no-config" "file:///C:/Users/johnd/vllu/src/bin/compile.js" "$@"

and
% generated by deno install %
@deno "run" "--allow-all" "--no-config" "file:///C:/Users/johnd/vllu/src/bin/compile.js" %*

I don't understand why those command lines include the '--no-config' option since my project root contains a deno.jsonc file, and according to the help docs for 'deno install' (running 'deno install --help') clearly states (for option --config):
  -c, --config <FILE>                 Configure different aspects of deno including TypeScript, linting, and code formatting
                                        Typically the configuration file will be called `deno.json` or `deno.jsonc` and
                                        automatically detected; in that case this flag is not necessary.

Am I doing something wrong? Meanwhile, I'll try explicitly using the --config option with deno install.
